# jqGrid - How to delete associated tables?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is it possible using jqGrid to load data from a table (parent table) but when I want to delete a record, it should first delete the associated records in the child table, because of the Foreign Key constraint.

If yes, how to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set cascade delete on the fk constraints in the database.

the grid has nothing to do with the process really except for sending the signal to your back end.

Comment: Hi Sky, thanks for the response. The problem is, as one of our standards, we don't perform cascade update/delete to our tables. If that can be done on the application-level that is really great for us.